# Implementing Smooth Navigation in Next.js Blog Website with Database-Fetched Article Links

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm developing a blog website using Next.js, where I aim to provide seamless navigation between articles. Next.js offers a Link component for smooth client-side navigation within the application. However, when fetching articles dynamically from a database, the traditional anchor tag approach disrupts this smooth navigation experience. Instead, I want to leverage the Next.js Link component for database-fetched article links to maintain the benefits of client-side rendering and avoid full-page reloads.

I attempted to replace the traditional anchor tags () with the Next.js Link component to enable smooth client-side navigation. Despite this change, the navigation functionality did not work as expected, and the links still resulted in full-page reloads instead of the desired seamless navigation within the Next.js application.

Comment: Please provide code sample of how you are approaching this.

Comment: I fetched the blog html from database. I tried to replace all `<a href=""></a>` with <Link> component. I used regex to get the href, attributes and innerText. But I can't think anymore that how can I do it.